# If a sequence is absolutely summable does this imply that the sum of the terms squared is finite.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a proof or counter example to the statement
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_j| < \infty \Rightarrow \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_j^2 < \infty,
\end{align*}

where $\psi_j \in \mathbb{R}$. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\sum_{j} |\psi_j| < \infty$ implies that $M:= \sup_j|\psi_j| < \infty$. Thus

$$\sum_j \psi_j^2 \leq \sum_j |\psi_j|M = M \sum_j|\psi_j| < \infty$$